# I can't change language on my android app by system setting

Tags: android, locale

I have two strings.xml files, one is default, the other is values-zh . The problem is whatever I need to change the phone system language , my app strings always is Chinese.
But if I use such fuction code to change language , it works.

```
 public static final String EN = "en";
 public static final String ZH = "zh";

  public void changeLanguage(String language) {
    Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    if(language.equals(ZH)){
        configuration.locale = Locale.CHINESE;
    }else if(language.equals(EN)){
        configuration.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    }else {
        configuration.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        language = EN;
    }
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration , displayMetrics);
    AbSharedUtil.putString(mContext , "language" , language);
    mContext.finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext , MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);



}
```

So the problem is I can change language by code , but I can't not change it by system language settings automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code.

```
        Locale myLocale = new Locale("zh");
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Comment: My default strings.xml is English . What I want is if I go to the phone Settings to change language like English(United States) , and my app also can change automatically. However it's not like this . Whatever I change any language , it always show Chinese(values-zh).

Comment: use this method after condition. Locale.setDefault(configuration.locale).

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have not added [android:configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) with the parameter "locale" in your manifest, this would cause your app not to reload resources when the system locale change.

Comment: every activity？

Comment: Yes, of course. Each activity declaring configChanges with "locale" will not be destroyed and will not reload resources on locale change.